# How many random numbers does std::uniform_real_distribution use?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I was surprised to see that the output of this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng1;
    std::mt19937 rng2;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist;

    double random = dist(rng1);
    rng2.discard(2);

    std::cout << (rng1() - rng2()) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

is `0` - i.e. `std::uniform_real_distribution` uses **two** random numbers to produce a random `double` value in the range [0,1). I thought it would just generate one and rescale that. After thinking about it I guess that this is because `std::mt19937` produces 32-bit ints and double is twice this size and thus not "random enough".

Question: How do I find out this number generically, i.e. if the random number generator and the floating point type are arbitrary types?

Edit: I just noticed that I could use `std::generate_canonical` instead, as I am only interested in random numbers of [0,1). Not sure if this makes a difference.

Comment: You can't find this generically.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: because...

Comment: As an aside, think of what it would mean to "rescale" a 32-bit integer to a 64-bit double: there are approximately 2^62 distinct double values. There are 2^32 distinct int values. This means that only **one out of every billion** possible double values would be representable in the resulting double. This is clearly unacceptable.

Comment: JohannesD: Thats just what I guessed above. Thanks for stating it in much clearer words!

Comment: @JohannesD But you don't want to generate all 2^62 values, or at least not with equal frequency.  I'd go for generating 2^52, in order to ensure an equal distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `template<class RealType, size_t bits, class URNG> std::generate_canonical` the standard (section 27.5.7.2) explicitly defines the number of calls to the uniform random number generator (URNG) to be

max(1, b / log_2 R),

where b is the minimum of the number of bits in the mantissa of the RealType and the number of bits given to generate_canonical as template parameter.
R is the range of numbers the URNG can return `(URNG::max()-URNG::min()+1)`.
However, in your example this will not make any difference, since you need 2 calls to the mt19937 to fill the 53 bits of the mantissa of the double.

For other distributions the standard does not provide a generic way to get any information on how many numbers the URNG has to generate to obtain one number of the distribution.

A reason might be that for some distributions the number uniform random numbers required to generate a single number of the distribution is not fixed and may vary from call to call. An example is the `std::poisson_distribution`, which is usually implemented as a loop which draws a uniform random number in each iteration until the product of these numbers has reached a certain threshold (see for example the [implementation of the GNU C++ library](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2b%2b-v3/include/bits/random.tcc;hb=503700a925ac27ea615eecb149062442c869a0f0) (line 1523-1528)).